# is the method continuing "running"

Tags: android, methods, onclick

My question is ,if the place event listener(inside method changestatus() )continues executing after click event happens, or is called only once.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (b1.getText()=="Start" && name!=null ) {
        b1.setText("Stop");
        inte.barstatus();
        inte.respond("Trying to find buildings near you");
        changestatus();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have to get close to another building.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (b1.getText()=="Start"){
        b1.setText("Stop");
        inte.barstatus();
        inte.respond("Trying to find buildings near you");
        changestatus();
    }
    else{
    b1.setText("Start");
    inte.barstatus2();
    inte.respond("Press Start button to find buildings near you");
            }
}
public void changestatus(){
        placeEventListener = new PlaceEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
                super.onVisitStart(visit);
                name = visit.getPlace().getName().toString();
                switch (name) {
                    case "test1": {
                        inte.respond(name.toString());
                        inte.barstatus2();
                        ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "test2": {
                        inte.respond(name.toString());
                        inte.barstatus2();
                        ToneGenerator toneY = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
                        toneY.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Joylamp": {
                        inte.respond(name.toString());
                        inte.barstatus2();
                        ToneGenerator toneT = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
                        toneT.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

.......................................................
I hope you can understand my question.
Thanks

EDIT
i forgot this part of the code, which is inside changestatus() method:

```
placeManager = PlaceManager.getInstance();
        placeManager.addListener(placeEventListener);
        placeManager.startMonitoring();
        CommunicationManager.getInstance().startReceivingCommunications();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `PlaceEventListener` but you are not assigning it to a `PlaceManager` (like `placeManager.addListener(placeEventListener);`

This way, after method `changestatus()` is executed and finished, your `placeEventListener` can be collected by Garbage Collector (since no one is referencing it).

I believe your `placeEventListener` won't never receive any event.

**UPDATE**

You updated your question...

Now, we can see that `placeEventListener` will remains alive and receiving events. So, it will continuously run until you call `placeManager.getInstance().removeListener()`

If you don't remove-it, it will keep running as long as `placeManager()` remains alive... So, I suggest to improve your code add some condition to stop listening the events... Something like:

```
public class TestClass extends Activity {
    private PlaceEventListener placeEventListener;


    public void changestatus(){
        if(placeEventListener == null) {
            placeEventListener = new PlaceEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
                    super.onVisitStart(visit);
                    ....
                    ...
                }
            }

            CommunicationManager placeManager = PlaceManager.getInstance();
            placeManager.addListener(placeEventListener);
            placeManager.startMonitoring();
            placeManager.startReceivingCommunications();
        }

    }

    /*
        Remember to add conditions to stop monitoring...
        Otherwise, you listener will remains running even when you no longer need.
        Also, placeManager is a static method.. so, it last longer than your activity/class...
        If you don't remove your listener when your object/activity is being destroyed, you can induce memory leaks

        So, if you add a listener, remember to remove it
    */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(placeEventListener != null) {
            CommunicationManager placeManager = PlaceManager.getInstance();
            placeManager.removeListener(placeEventListener);
            placeManager.stopMonitoring();
            placeManager.stopReceivingCommunications();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```